# Calling followup intent multiple times

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-home, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am working on a estimate tool for google actions where I want the ability for the user to change individual values after they get an initial estimate. Currently I am using follow up intentions to update values and then invoke the estimation intention, it seems to fail always. I think it is related to contexts. Is there a good resource to understand contexts and debug for them?

Comment: It would be helpful if you updated your question to show an example of the Intents that you're having trouble with, along with an illustration of what you're trying to do, how Dialogflow responds, and what you're expecting instead. StackOverflow works best trying to provide specific answers, rather than references that can easily be googled.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Followup Intents, you're certainly getting tangled up in [Contexts](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-overview). Google's documentation is simple, but covers the issue well.

Without seeing your Intents specifically, it is difficult to see what you're doing, how you're trying to do it, and what problem you may be encountering. However... Followup Intents are not usually good for long chains of questions and answers, particularly if you're expecting the user to go back and correct some of the answers.

Instead, you should leave them as top-level Intents, either triggerable only in specific contexts, or triggerable at any point (or both) depending on exactly what your conversation sounds like.